# Pivot a lot of data using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I m using SQL Server 2008 R2 and have this table:

```
ID  Phrase
1   smeels
2   like  
3   teen 
4   spirit
```

But the number of phrases is like about 20 000 and my goal is to "turn it other way" so to get the output like this:

```
ID Smeels Like Teen Spirit
1   1      0    0     0
2   0      1    0     0
3   0      0    1     0
4   0      0    0     1
```

Tried to use CASE with Pivot function but I don't know how to handle with big amount of columns. How can I deal with this task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't really have a result set with 20,000 columns, so what you want to do isn't possible.

Comment: Dont look only on pivot function-if it is still a way would be nice

Comment: Have your application do that (it's going to have to iterate through everything one row at a time anyway).

Comment: If you have ssrs installed then you can do this with a matrix/table and a column group.

Comment: Take a step back - why are you doing this? Is it for presentation of a report? Is it for fiddling in Excel? A dataset with between 1 and 20,000 columns is of no practical use in a database so this must be for some other purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, you would use a pivot.  See explanation from bluefeet here: [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

However, as Gordon Linoff said, you cannot do this with 20,000 columns.`